# Hibernate AutoCommit Example in Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I just started learning Hibernate, but based on the reading I have done in the manual, the below code appears to be using auto-commit as commit() is not being explicitly called. All of the examples I found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) show use of commit(). Since I am just learning I wanted to get confirmation from the community that I was thinking the right way.

```
this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();    
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
session.clear();
entityReturned = (MultipleKeyTable) session.get(MultipleKeyTable.class, entityId);
session.close();
```

**Edit**
I should have mentioned that the `hibernate.connection.autocommit` is not defined in config and I believe that by default it is set to true.

**Edit**
I was wrong `hibernate.connection.autocommit` is set to false by default. Thanks Apostolos .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup the autocommit mode at hibernate via  `hibernate.connection.autocommit` 
property

please read [the configuration documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties)

Based on your updated question, you are not using `autocommit` since you didnt specify the `autocommit` in your configuration. You are also making a `select query`, so you wont see if something happens in your db. make some changes, save them and then check again. 
You need to commit your transaction in order to save the changes, or define `autocommit = true` at your properties.

Comment: The `hibernate.connection.autocommit` property, if not defined, is set to true (from what I have read). At this point I can't really change that. I am trying to understand whether the code I posted is using autocommit. If it is, the I need to demarcate my code to to handle the the commit explicitly as I do not want to use autocommit.

Comment: by default it is set to false and it is not best practice to set it to true. in order to see if autocommit is enabled, please make an action (insert/update/delete) and then see the results. with this example, you just read a row. i'm pretty sure though that when hibernate starts, it logs which autocommit value is being used.

Comment: so, as you updated your question, you are not using autocommit since you didnt specify the autocommit in your configuration. you are also making a select query, so you wont see if sth happens in your db. make some changes, save them and then check again.

Comment: Ok thanks. I see now that by default it is false. So in the code above, even though I don't call commit(), the session.close() is properly closing the transaction? Or is it best to call commit() explicitly and let that close the session?

Comment: `close()` is closing the session. if you start a transaction, it is best to commit it, even though it is only a select query. since you are closing the session, transaction is lost too. but in order to write good code, you have to commit the transaction if you begin it and also handle the exception by rolling it back.

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much Apostolos. :)